# Using the place method within a scrollable frame

Tags: python, tkinter

I want to use the .place geometry manager in Tkinter because I need to declare absolute locations of items within a scrollable frame. I am having a hard time finding a good explanation of how to use the .place options to draw the widgets within a frame. The following does not draw the label widgets:

```
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import ttk

root = tk.Tk()
root.geometry("700x475")

def yscroll(*args):
    scrollcan.yview(*args)

# building major geometry needed for scrolling

scrollcan = tk.Canvas(root, height=300, width=300)
scrollcan.grid(row=0, column=0)

y_gridscroll = ttk.Scrollbar(root, orient="vertical", command = yscroll)
y_gridscroll.grid(row=0, column=1, sticky="n"+"s")

gridframe = tk.Frame(scrollcan)
# don't need to pack or grid it this way, needed to make it scroll
scrollcan.create_window((0,0), window=gridframe, anchor="nw") 
    
# creating and drawing content

a = tk.Label(gridframe, text = "aaa", relief = "groove")
b = tk.Label(gridframe, text = "bbb", relief = "groove")
c = tk.Label(gridframe, text = "ccc", relief = "groove")

a.place(width = 30, height = 21, x = 10, y = 10)
b.place(width = 30, height = 21, x = 50, y = 50)
c.place(width = 30, height = 21, x = 90, y = 90)

# configuring

scrollcan.bind('<Configure>', lambda e: scrollcan.configure(scrollregion = scrollcan.bbox("all")))

scrollcan.config(yscrollcommand = y_gridscroll.set)

root.mainloop()
```

Comment: gridframe is ending up with a size of 0x0.  If you assign a width and height when you create it, it works.

Comment: Using `.place()` to put widgets will not adjust the size of the parent frame.